# Spherical Twist Equivalence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

I have just started to study spherical objects with Huybrechts book, and I can not solve this (I suppose simple) exercise:

Let $\mathcal E\in D^b(X)$ be a spherical object, show that $T_\mathcal E \simeq  T_{\mathcal E[1]} $, where $T$ is the spherical twist.

I know that $\mathcal E[1]$ is also a spherical object, but I have no idea in how to solve using this.

Comment: Did you try to use the definition of $T_{\mathcal{E}}$?

Comment: You mean as the Fourier-Mukai transform? I am trying, it may be simple, but I cannot see how to solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spherical twist $T_{\mathcal{E}}$ is given by the Fourier--Mukai functor with kernel
$$
Cone(\mathcal{E} \boxtimes \mathcal{E}^\vee \to \mathcal{O}_\Delta)
$$
on $X \times X$, where the morphism is the composition of the restriction to the diagonal and the trace map.

If you replace $\mathcal{E}$ by $\mathcal{E}[1]$, the first term will be replaced by
$$
\mathcal{E}[1] \boxtimes (\mathcal{E}[1])^\vee \cong
\mathcal{E}[1] \boxtimes \mathcal{E}^\vee[-1] \cong
\mathcal{E} \boxtimes \mathcal{E}^\vee.
$$
This canonical isomorphism is compatible with the restriction to the diagonal and with the trace map, hence the Fourier--Mukai kernels for $T_{\mathcal{E}}$ and $T_{\mathcal{E}[1]}$ are isomorphic, hence the functors are isomorphic as well.