# Spherical twist and shift functor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, derived-categories

Answers to questions on this page ([Spherical Twist Equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2956505/spherical-twist-equivalence)) include:

> $$\mathcal{E}[1] \boxtimes (\mathcal{E}[1])^\vee \cong \mathcal{E}[1]
>  \boxtimes \mathcal{E}^\vee[-1] \cong \mathcal{E} \boxtimes
>  \mathcal{E}^\vee.$$

What is the reason for $(\mathcal{E}[1])^\vee \simeq \mathcal{E}^\vee[-1]$ here? Also, do they use the assumption of spherical?

In the argument, $\mathcal{E}$ is a spherical object in $D^b(X)$, bounded derived category consisted by coherent sheaves on a smooth projective variety X, i.e., (i) $\mathcal{E} \otimes \omega_X \simeq \mathcal{E}$, (ii) $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{E}, \mathcal{E}[i]) = k$ (if $i = 0$ or $\operatorname{dim} X$), $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{E}, \mathcal{E}[i]) = 0$ (otherwise).

Thank you.

EDIT : 
I understand like that
$$(\mathcal{E}[1])^\vee = R\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{E}[1], \mathcal{O}_X), $$
$$\mathcal{E}^\vee[-1] = (R\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{E}, \mathcal{O}_X))[-1]. $$
Honestly, I don't have the right intuition about function: "Apply a shift". I would appreciate it if you could tell me how you understand this.

Comment: No assumption is used. Just recall the definition of the shift and duality functors.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I think:
$(\mathcal{E}[1])^\vee = R\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{E}[1], \mathcal{O}_X)$, 
$\mathcal{E}^\vee[-1] = (R\mathcal{H}om(\mathcal{E}, \mathcal{O}_X))[-1]$. To be honest, I don't seem to have the right intuition about how to understand the function "Apply a shift".

Comment: What do you need intuition for? This sort of grading manipulation is just the definition of shifting + the definition of homs in a category of complexes.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\rhomm}{R \mathrm{Hom}} \newcommand{\rhom}{R \mathcal{H} om} \newcommand{\Homm}{\mathrm{Hom}} \newcommand{\Hom}{\mathcal{H} om}$I'll be using notation from this [Stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A5W) article, plus [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A8H) one. Note that in the Stacks project, the arguments of the derived hom are not complexes, but they define it to be $\Homm^\bullet$ which does take complexes as arguments, so I don't think it matters that I will put complexes as arguments of the derived hom. As per the discussion in p. 76 of Huybrechts' book, I think it's also OK for me to switch $R\mathrm{Hom}$ in the Stacks article to $\rhom$, and $\Homm$ to $\Hom$.

---

Write $\rhom_{D(R)}(L^\bullet, M^\bullet) = \Hom^\bullet(L^\bullet, M^\bullet)$. In turn, $\Hom^\bullet(L^\bullet, M^\bullet)$ is given as 
$$ \Hom^n(L^\bullet, M^\bullet) = \prod_{n=p+q} \Hom_R(L^{-q}, M^p).  $$
Then $\rhom_{D(R)}(L^\bullet[1], M^\bullet) = \Hom^\bullet(L^\bullet[1], M^\bullet) $ which is given by 
$$ \Hom^n(L^\bullet[1], M^\bullet) = \prod_{n=p+q} \Hom_R(L^{-q+1}, M^p).  $$
On the other hand, $\rhom_{D(R)}(L^\bullet, M^\bullet)[-1] = \Hom^\bullet(L^\bullet, M^\bullet)[-1] $ which is given by 
\begin{align} \Hom^n(L^\bullet, M^\bullet)[-1] &= \prod_{n-1=p+q} \Hom_R(L^{-q}, M^p) \\
&= \prod_{n=p+q+1} \Hom_R(L^{-q}, M^p) \\ &= \prod_{n=p+\tilde{q}} \Hom_R(L^{-q}, M^p) \\ &= \prod_{n=p+\tilde{q}} \Hom_R(L^{-\tilde{q}+1}, M^p) \end{align}
where we have used $\tilde{q} = q+1$, so $\rhom_{D(R)}(L^\bullet[1], M^\bullet) \cong \rhom_{D(R)}(L^\bullet, M^\bullet)[-1] $. Your case $\mathcal{E}[1]^\vee \cong \mathcal{E}^\vee [-1]$ is a special instance of this.